# Can I use a defined variable as an argument in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a variable in place of the ID parameter of an OnEvent() function.
I have several home buttons that I am coding. They all have unique ids, but do the same thing: return to the home screen. On the home screen you press a button to travel to "screen1" and sets the variable currentScreen = 1. Below is the code that performs this.

```
//declaring variables
var currentScreen;

//Send user to Screen 1
    onEvent("screenButton1", "click", function()
    {
      setScreen("Screen1");
      currentScreen = 1;
    });

//Send user to Home
    onEvent("homeButton" + currentScreen, "click", function()
    {
      setScreen("homeScreen");
    });
```

This is so I do not have to write code for every home button that exists. However, I am met with the following error, "WARNING: Line: 22: The onEvent() id parameter refers to an id ("homeButtonundefined") which does not exist." For some reason, it does not remember that I have set the value of currentScreen to 1. I am brand new to coding and am using code.org to learn. I don't know if that is relevant to this question, but if it is then better safe than sorry. Thanks for the help.

Comment: At the time `onEvent` is *set*, `currentScreen` isn't defined yet. It doesn't magically change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the event handler only after it's clicked, before reading it, or store the event in a variable that you can modify later somehow

```
var currentScreen, ev

//Send user to Screen 1
    onEvent("screenButton1", "click", function()
    {
      setScreen("Screen1");
      currentScreen = 1;
if(ev) reset(ev)//make a function to delete event
ev=onEvent("homeButton" + currentScreen, "click", function()
    {
      setScreen("homeScreen");
    });

//Make sure it has a return value
    });
```